# Ошибки GF4(OpenAI) Кодировка

Tags: python, python-openai

Работаю с OpenAI через G4F, вроде все отлично НО при работе часто бывают ошибки от локального сервера G4F

1. Самая частая, в основном при работе с русским. (Вроде решается изменением кодировки в файле библиотеки, но это не очень правильно)

> ```
> response_data += stream.decode()
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 15: unexpected end of
> ```

2. Появляется в основном. Я понимаю что там написано, но я не понимаю что именно не так

> ```
> raise RuntimeError("Incorrect response") 
> RuntimeError: Incorrect response
> ```

Последний кусок кода из библиотеки:

```
async with session.post("https://www.chatbase.co/api/fe/chat", json=data, proxy=proxy) as response:
response.raise_for_status()
response_data = ""
async for stream in response.content.iter_any():
    response_data += stream.decode()
    for incorrect_response in cls.list_incorrect_responses:
        if incorrect_response in response_data:
            raise RuntimeError("Incorrect response")
    yield stream.decode()
```

Comment: `response_data += stream.decode()` - это в вашем коде или в коде библиотеки?

Comment: Да это в библиотеки